# PHP sort a complicated multi-dimensional array by timestamp

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [type] => comment
            [batch] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T001
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 11:29:00
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T003
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 11:33:00
                            )
                    )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [type] => status
            [batch] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T002
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 11:31:00
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T004
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 12:32:00
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T006
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 12:33:00
                            )
                    )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [type] => status
            [batch] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T005
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 12:34:00
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T007
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 13:35:00
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T008
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 10:36:00
                            )
                    )
        )
)
```

I would like to re-order the array by **only** the **last datetime** inside the sub array [batch]

the result should be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [type] => status
            [batch] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T005
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 12:34:00
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T007
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 13:35:00
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T008
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 10:36:00
                            )
                    )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [type] => comment
            [batch] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T001
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 11:29:00
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T003
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 11:33:00
                            )
                    )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [type] => status
            [batch] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T002
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 11:31:00
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T004
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 12:32:00
                            )
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => T006
                                [datetime] => 2010-05-15 12:33:00
                            )
                    )
        )
)
```

Can I do it with "array_multisort"? Please suggest. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `usort` which allows you to sort an array using a user-defined comparison function. ([PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php))

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $lastTimestampA = end($a['batch']);
    $lastTimestampB = end($b['batch']);
    return strtotime($lastTimestampA['datetime']) > strtotime($lastTimestampB['datetime']);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! ~~~~~~~~                
I've this error ==>              
usort(): Array was modified by the user comparison function ~~~~~~

If I do it @usort( .... ), the array wasn't sort.